# Send personalized email (different template) on customer registration on magento2

Tags: magento2, customer, email-templates

Is there a way to send a different email template on customer's registration based on some params (for example the customer gender)?

For example: A male customer receive an email (defined in Maketing->email templates) with the id 11, and a female customer on registration receive the email with the id 12.

I have to overwrite all the customer module?

Comment: still a relevant question. I'm searching for the same thing...

Comment: Interesting. You can create an observer for this :) just a flying idea :)

Answer (score 0):

**Customize Email Template, Transactional Email:**

- Step 1: Load the Default Template
- Step 2: Fill out the Template Information
- Step 3: Preview the Template
- Step 4: Apply the new Template

**Step 1: Load the Default Template**

- On the Admin Panel, Marketing > Communications > Email Templates.
- Click on Add New Template,Choose the types of the Template: Header, Footer, or Message Templates.
- Click on Load Template, the corresponding format will appear.

[image]

**Step 2: Fill out the Template Information**

- Name for the new template in the `Template Name` field.
- Insert the `Template Subject` for the organization of the templates. The list of templates can be sorted and filtered by the Subject column.

[image]

- Customize the HTML as you need in the `Template Content` box.
- Click on `Insert Variable` to insert a variable in the `Template Content` box.

[image]

With the inserted variable, you can custom it directly into the template.

- If you want to declare any CSS, enter the styles in the `Template Styles` box.

**Step 3: Preview the Template**

- To ensure that the template is applied correctly as you expect, click on `Preview Template` to adjust if need.
- `Save Template` to complete.

Each completed new template is auto-updated in the list of available Email templates.

**Step 4: Apply the new Template**

Footer/ Header Template

- Go to Magento Admin, follow the path: `Store > Configuration > Customers > Customer Configuration`

Basing on where the template is placed to open the relevant option. For example, the template belongs to Create New Account Options:[image]

- Set the new template for `Welcome Email`.
- `Save Config` to complete

[Refrence](http://www.mageplaza.com)

Hope This will help :)

Comment: I know this, but I need to send different email on different customer on registration. In this way I'll send alway the defined email.

Comment: You could use customer groups functionality to achieve this.

Comment: How can I send diffent email per different group?